# Resize the canvas while entering and leaving fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

I would like to resize the canvas on entering and leaving the fullscreen. I am using three.js and its `THREE.WebGLRenderer`.

Using the code below I can do this but it sets the dimensions of windows "one iteration back" - meaning when I enter the fullscreen it sets the smaller height(buts the bottom part) and then I leave the fullscreen it overstretches it in vertical dimension.

code:

```
  var width  = window.innerWidth,
      height = window.innerHeight;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(width, height);

  function toggleFullscreen(){
    var docElm = document.documentElement;
    if(!document.fullscreen){
      if (docElm.requestFullscreen) {
          docElm.requestFullscreen();
      }   
      else if (docElm.mozRequestFullScreen) {
          docElm.mozRequestFullScreen();
      }   
      else if (docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
          docElm.webkitRequestFullScreen();
      }   
      else if (docElm.msRequestFullscreen) {
          docElm.msRequestFullscreen();
      }   
      document.fullscreen = true;
    } 
    else{
      if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
      }   
      else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      }   
      else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
          document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }   
      else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
      }   
      document.fullscreen = false;
    }
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  }

...

<body>
<div onclick="toggleFullscreen()" id="button">Fullscreen</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setSize()` function in the `toggleFullscreen()` function is called before entering or leaving full screen. That means size of the renderer is set by previous window size.

Entering or leaving full screen by `requestFullscreen` or `exitFullscreen` trigger `onresize` event, so write `setSize()` function in the `onresize` event handler function.

```
window.onresize = function() {
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok the worst and the only solution that I could come up with so far is to add this add the end of callback function

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
}, 500);
```

Please tell me how bad it is and give another solution :)

Comment: Unironically, this seems to be the best solution as especially on OS X there is a pronounced delay due to the animation of leaving full screen that makes it seemingly impossible to redraw an element in the correct size until after this animation is fully completed.

Answer (score 0):

If you [follow best practices](http://games.greggman.com/game/webgl-anti-patterns/) fullscreen just works, no changes needed to your three.js code.

[Here's a working example that follows best practices](http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/three-by-css/three-by-css-fullscreen.html) (click anywhere to go fullscreen). Also here's [a bunch more samples that all use the same code](http://greggman.com/downloads/examples/three-by-css/three-by-css.html) showing you don't have to change any code for all the different use cases when you follow best practices

Best practices in this case means using CSS and embracing the browser instead of fighting against it. That means set up your CSS so your canvas (and other elements) stretch or scale or move wherever and however you want them to. Then lookup what the browser did and set the backingstore of your canvas to match.

Here's resizing code that works when you let CSS do what it's supposed to do.

```
// Resize by clientWidth and clientHeight
var resize = function() {
    var width  = canvas.clientWidth;
    var height = canvas.clientHeight;
    if (canvas.width  != width ||
        canvas.height != height ) {

          // You have to pass false here otherwise three.js does
          // arguably the wrong thing and fights the CSS.

          renderer.setSize( canvas.clientWidth, canvas.clientHeight, false );

        camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }
};
```

Now set your canvas CSS to be 100% size

```
canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block; /* remove's the extra space that causes a scrollbar */
}
```

If you have the canvas inside a container like another div set that to also be 100% size and also set the `body,html` to be 100% size

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you're rendering every frame just call it in your render loop end you're done.

```
var render = function() {
    resize();

    ...

    renderer.render( scene, camera );

    requestAnimationFrame( render, canvas );
};
render();
```

If you're not rendering every frame then call resize when you do render and call render when the screen resizes or via a ResizeObserver.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not always as easy to "just use css" to scale elements. For more complicated drawing operations onto a canvas, where the exact dimensions of the canvas need to be known to draw elements of a specific size, for example a grid, it is impossible to rely on simple css for auto scaling.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example? I'm not sure what you mean, "For example a grid".  Also see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47696956/display-pixel-perfect-canvas-on-all-devices/72611819#72611819

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the solution, e.g. using ResizeObserver, and that's what we're doing right now. It's hard to give a concrete example in the limited available space in these comments, but in general, we're rendering a game board which requires several canvas layers and draws a variety of objects onto those layers. The sizing of all those objects, layers and grid, is highly dependent on the canvas size. Canvas size is not known until the canvas is rendered. Canvas cannot be rendered until size is known. So some trickery is needed.

Comment: You'd have to make a small repo for me to see the issue. It doesn't make a lot of sense to say you can't know the size until you render since you can't render without knowing the size.  Maybe you're saying you decide on a grid size, the compute the size canvas you need to display that grid, then check what size the canvas actually is, then render? But solution doesn't seem like it would work for lots of reasons. Zoom being one.

Answer (score 0):

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );

var canvas = renderer.domElement;
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(){
    canvas.requestFullscreen = canvas.requestFullscreen || 
        canvas.mozRequestFullScreen || 
        canvas.webkitRequestFullscreen || 
        canvas.msRequestFullscreen;
    canvas.requestFullscreen();
});
document.body.appendChild( canvas );

window.addEventListener('resize', function(event){
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight );
});
```