# Display pixel-perfect canvas on all devices

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I have some canvases that I want to be displayed pixel-perfect in every (modern) browser. By default, devices with high-DPI screens are scaling my page so that everything looks the right size, but it's breaking* the appearance of my canvases.

How can I ensure that one pixel in my canvas = one pixel on the screen? Preferably this wouldn't affect other elements on the page, since I still want e.g. text to be scaled appropriately for the device.

I already tried styling the canvas dimensions based on `window.devicePixelRatio`. That makes the canvases the right size but the contents look even worse. I'm guessing that just scales them down after they're already scaled up incorrectly.

*If you care, because the canvases use dithering and the browsers are doing some kind of lerp rather than nearest-neighbor

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The currently marked answer is wrong

There is no way to get a pixel perfect canvas on all devices across all browsers in 2022.

You might think it's working using

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

But all you have to do to see it fail is press Zoom-In/Zoom-Out. Zooming is not the only place it will fail. Many devices and many OSes have fractional devicePixelRatio.

In other words. Let's say you make a 100x100 canvas (enlarged).

[image: 100x100 image canvas]

The user's devicePixelRatio is 1.25 (which is what my Desktop PC is). The canvas will then display at 125x125 pixels and your 100x100 pixel canvas will get scaled to 125x125 with nearest neighbor filtering (image-rendering: pixelated) and look really crappy as some pixels are 1x1 pixel big and others 2x2 pixels big.

[image]

So no, using

```
image-rendering: pixelated;
image-rendering: crisp-edges;
```

by itself is not a solution.

Worse. The browser works in fractional sizes but the device does not. Example:

```js
let totalWidth = 0;
let totalDeviceWidth = 0;
document.querySelectorAll(".split>*").forEach(elem => {
  const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
  const width = rect.width;
  const deviceWidth = width * devicePixelRatio;
  totalWidth += width;
  totalDeviceWidth += deviceWidth;
  log(`${elem.className.padEnd(6)}: width = ${width}, deviceWidth: ${deviceWidth}`);
});

const elem = document.querySelector('.split');
const rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
const width = rect.width;
const deviceWidth = width * devicePixelRatio;

log(`
totalWidth      : ${totalWidth}
totalDeviceWidth: ${totalDeviceWidth}

elemWidth       : ${width}
elemDeviceWidth : ${deviceWidth}`);

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.split {
  width: 299px;
  display: flex;
}
.split>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
.left {
  background: pink;
}
.middle {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.right {
  background: lightblue;
}
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="split">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The sample above there is 299 CSS pixel wide div and inside there are 3 child divs each taking 1/3 of their parent. Asking for sizes by calling `getBoundingClientRect` on my MacBook Pro in Chrome 102 I get

```
left  : width = 99.6640625, deviceWidth: 199.328125
middle: width = 99.6640625, deviceWidth: 199.328125
right : width = 99.6640625, deviceWidth: 199.328125

totalWidth      : 298.9921875
totalDeviceWidth: 597.984375

elemWidth       : 299
elemDeviceWidth : 598
```

Add them up and you might see a problem. According to `getBoundingClientRect` each one is about 1/3 width in device pixels (199.328125). You can't actually have 0.328125 device pixels so they'll need to be converted to integers. Let's use `Math.round` so they all become 199.

```
199 + 199 + 199 = 597
```

But according to the browser the size of the parent is 598 device pixels big. Where is the missing pixel?

Let's ask

```js
const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    let good = false;
    if (entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize) {
      // NOTE: Only this path gives the correct answer
      // The other paths are imperfect fallbacks
      // for browsers that don't provide anyway to do this
      width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
      height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
      good = true;
    } else {
      if (entry.contentBoxSize) {
        if (entry.contentBoxSize[0]) {
          width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
          height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
        } else {
          width = entry.contentBoxSize.inlineSize;
          height = entry.contentBoxSize.blockSize;
        }
      } else {
        width = entry.contentRect.width;
        height = entry.contentRect.height;
      }
      width *= devicePixelRatio;
      height *= devicePixelRatio;
    }
    log(`${entry.target.className.padEnd(6)}: width = ${width} measure = ${good ? "good" : "bad (not accurate)"}`);    
  }
});

document.querySelectorAll('.split>*').forEach(elem => {
  observer.observe(elem);
});

function log(...args) {
  const elem = document.createElement('pre');
  elem.textContent = args.join(' ');
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```css
.split {
  width: 299px;
  display: flex;
}
.split>* {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  height: 50px;
}
.left {
  background: pink;
}
.middle {
  background: lightgreen;
}
.right {
  background: lightblue;
}
pre { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="split">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="middle"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

The code above asks using `ResizeObserver` and `devicePixelContentBoxSize` which is only supported on Chromium browsers and Firefox at the moment. For me, the middle div got the extra pixel

```
left  : width = 199
middle: width = 200
right : width = 199
```

The point of all of that is

1. You can't just naively set `image-rendering: pixelated; image-rendering: crisp-edges`
2. If you want to know how many pixels are in the canvas you may have to ask and you can only find out on Chrome/Firefox ATM

Solutions: TL;DR **THERE IS NO CROSS BROWSER SOLUTION IN 2022**

- In Chrome/Firefox you can use the ResizeObserver solution above.
- In Chrome and Firefox you can also compute a fractional sized canvas

  In other words. A typical "fill the page" canvas like

  ```
  <style>
  html, body, canvas { margin: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block; }
  <style>
  <body>
    <canvas>
    </canvas>
  <body>
  ```

  will not work. See reasons above. But you can do this

  1. get the size of the container (the body in this case)
  2. multiply by devicePixelRatio and round down
  3. divide by the devicePixelRatio
  4. Use that value for the canvas CSS width and height and the #2 value for the canvas's width and heigh.

  This will end up leaving a trailing gap on the right and bottom edges
  of 1 to 3 device pixels but it should give you a canvas that is 1x1 pixels.

```js
const px = v => `${v}px`;

const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
resizeCanvas(canvas);
draw(canvas);

window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  resizeCanvas(canvas);
  draw(canvas);
});

function resizeCanvas(canvas) {
  // how many devicePixels per pixel in the canvas we want
  // you can set this to 1 if you always want 1 device pixel to 1 canvas pixel
  const pixelSize = Math.max(1, devicePixelRatio) | 0;  
  
  const rect = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const deviceWidth  = rect.width * devicePixelRatio | 0;
  const deviceHeight = rect.height * devicePixelRatio | 0;
  const pixelsAcross = deviceWidth / pixelSize | 0;
  const pixelsDown   = deviceHeight / pixelSize | 0;
  const devicePixelsAcross = pixelsAcross * pixelSize;
  const devicePixelsDown   = pixelsDown   * pixelSize;
  canvas.style.width = px(devicePixelsAcross / devicePixelRatio);
  canvas.style.height = px(devicePixelsDown / devicePixelRatio);
  canvas.width = pixelsAcross;
  canvas.height = pixelsDown;
}

function draw(canvas) {
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  for (let x = 0; x < canvas.width; ++x) {
    let h = x % (canvas.height * 2);
    if (h > canvas.height) {
      h = 2 * canvas.height - h;
    }
    ctx.fillStyle = 'lightblue';
    ctx.fillRect(x, 0, 1, h);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
    ctx.fillRect(x, h, 1, 1);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'pink';
    ctx.fillRect(x, h + 1, 1, canvas.height - h);
  }
}
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
/* set to red we can see the gap */
/* set to some other color to hide the gap */
  background: red; 
}

canvas {
  display: block;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

In Safari there are no solutions: Safari provides neither support for `devicePixelContentBoxSize` nor does it adjust the `devicePixelRatio` in response to zooming. On the plus side, Safari never returns a fractional `devicePixelRatio`, at least as of 2022 but you won't get 1x1 device pixels on Safari if the user zooms.

There's a proposal for [a CSS attribute `image-resolution`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-resolution), which if set to `snap` would help with this issue in CSS. Unfortunately, as for May 2023 it is not implemented in any browser.

Comment: Notwithstanding the above limitations, I have had some degree of success with CSS transforms, where the rendering of a very small canvas was not looking great, but making the canvas 2x larger, and then scaling it down by half with a simple CSS transform made it appear a lot crisper.

Answer (score 2):

For me, only a combination of different 'pixel perfect' techniques helped to archive the results:

1. Get and scale canvas with a pixel ratio:

   **pixelRatio = window.devicePixelRatio/ctx.backingStorePixelRatio**
2. Scale the canvas on the resize (avoid canvas default stretch scaling).
3. multiple the lineWidth with pixelRatio to find proper 'real' pixel line thickness:

   **context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;**

**NOTE: not sure wheter it's valid for all devices**

4. Check whether the thickness of the line is odd or even. add half of the pixelRatio to the line position for the odd thickness values.

   **x = x + pixelRatio/2;**

The odd line will be placed in the middle of the pixel. The line above is used to move it a little bit.

5. use image-rendering: pixelated;

```js
function getPixelRatio(context) {
  dpr = window.devicePixelRatio || 1,
    bsr = context.webkitBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.mozBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.msBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.oBackingStorePixelRatio ||
    context.backingStorePixelRatio || 1;

  return dpr / bsr;
}


var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pixelRatio = getPixelRatio(context);
var initialWidth = canvas.clientWidth * pixelRatio;
var initialHeight = canvas.clientHeight * pixelRatio;


window.addEventListener('resize', function(args) {
  rescale();
  redraw();
}, false);

function rescale() {
  var width = initialWidth * pixelRatio;
  var height = initialHeight * pixelRatio;
  if (width != context.canvas.width)
    context.canvas.width = width;
  if (height != context.canvas.height)
    context.canvas.height = height;

  context.setTransform(pixelRatio, 0, 0, pixelRatio, 0, 0);
}

function pixelPerfectLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {

  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  thickness = 1;
  // Multiple your stroke thickness  by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;

  context.strokeStyle = "Black";
  context.moveTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x1), getSharpPixel(thickness, y1));
  context.lineTo(getSharpPixel(thickness, x2), getSharpPixel(thickness, y2));
  context.stroke();
  context.restore();
}

function pixelPerfectRectangle(x, y, w, h, thickness, useDash) {
  context.save();
  // Pixel perfect rectange:
  context.beginPath();

  // Multiple your stroke thickness by a pixel ratio!
  context.lineWidth = thickness * pixelRatio;
  context.strokeStyle = "Red";
  if (useDash) {
    context.setLineDash([4]);
  }
  // use sharp x,y and integer w,h!
  context.strokeRect(
    getSharpPixel(thickness, x),
    getSharpPixel(thickness, y),
    Math.floor(w),
    Math.floor(h));
  context.restore();
}

function redraw() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  pixelPerfectLine(50,50,250,250);
  pixelPerfectLine(120,0,120,250);
  pixelPerfectLine(122,0,122,250);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(10, 11, 200.3, 43.2, 1, false);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(41, 42, 150.3, 43.2, 1, true);
  pixelPerfectRectangle(102, 100, 150.3, 243.2, 2, true);
}

function getSharpPixel(thickness, pos) {

  if (thickness % 2 == 0) {
    return pos;
  }
  return pos + pixelRatio / 2;

}

rescale();
redraw();
```

```css
canvas {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

NOTE: Resize event is not fired in the snipped, so might be not accurate.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approximation is this:

```
canvas {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

Browser support isn't [great](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering). I've tested this with Chrome, Firefox, and Safari on Windows, Mac, Linux, iOS, and Android: it gives you a canvas made up of individually controllable squares, which will correspond to pixels if the canvas is not zoomed in and the device has an integer display scale factor.

This has no effect on normal DPI devices as long as your canvases are being displayed at their normal size. Also, depending on the screen, you get interesting artifacts on high DPI devices, but I think that's unavoidable due to how those displays work. They're still better than the artifacts you get without the style.

---

I also tried upscaling all of my canvases 200% with nearest-neighbor in javascript and then setting them as background images of normal-sized divs. This is how Apple recommends displaying images for retina devices, so I thought it would give a great result. But you still end up with artifacts and they aren't fixed by zooming in the page so it's actually worse that the simple solution above.