# How do I use ResizeObserver with requestAnimationFrame correctly

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, resize-observer

Many examples show using `ResizeObserver` something like this

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.restore();
}

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const canvas = entry.target;
    canvas.width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
    canvas.height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
    draw();
  }
})
observer.observe(canvas);
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

This works. The `ResizeObserver` will fire once when started and then anytime the canvas's display size changes

But then, if you switch to a `requestAnimationFrame` loop you'll see an issue

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.rotate(performance.now() * 0.001);
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
   ctx.strokeRect(-5, -5, size / 4, 10);
   ctx.restore();
}

function rAFLoop() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const canvas = entry.target;
    canvas.width = entry.contentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
    canvas.height = entry.contentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
  }
})
observer.observe(canvas);
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Above, all I did was take the call to draw out of `ResizeObserver` and call it in a `requestAnimationFrame` loop (and added a little motion)

If you size the window now you'll see the circle flickers

How do I fix this?

Comment: Probably of interest: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/9721

Answer (score 3):

The issue here is the spec says that `ResizeObserver` callbacks happen **after requestAnimationFrame** callbacks. This means the order of operations in the example above is

1. requestAnimationFrame callback
2. draw circle
3. resize observer callback
4. set canvas size (setting the size clears the canvas)
5. browser composites page.

There are several workarounds, all of them have issues or are semi-involved

### Solution 1: Draw in the `ResizeObserver` too.

This will work. Unfortunately this means you're drawing twice in a single frame. If your drawing is heavy then that would lead to the resize feeling sluggish

### Solution 2: Don't use `ResizeObserver`

You can look up the display size of the canvas in multiple ways. (1) `canvas.clientWidth`, `canvas.clientHeight` (returns integers), (2) `canvas.getBoundingClientRect()` (returns rational numbers)

For example:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.rotate(performance.now() * 0.001);
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
   ctx.strokeRect(-5, -5, size / 4, 10);
   ctx.restore();
}

function rAFLoop() {
  // Only set canvas.width and canvas.height
  // if they need to be set because setting them is a
  // heavy operation
  if (canvas.width !== canvas.clientWidth ||
      canvas.height !== canvas.clientHeight) {
    canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
  }

  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Size the window and you'll see it no longer flickers

This solution will work but the those methods (`canvas.clientWidth/height` and/or `getBoundingClientRect`) only return CSS pixels, not device pixels. You can multiply either number by `devicePixelRatio` but that will also not give you the correct answer all of the time. You can read about why in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72611819/128511

### Solution 3: Check in rAF if the size of the canvas is going to change, if it is going to change then do not render and instead render in the `ResizeObserver` callback.

We can guess if the canvas is going to resize if `getBoundingClientRect` changes size. Even though we can't correctly convert from `getBoundingClientRect` to device pixels, the value will change from the previous time we called it if the canvas has been resized.

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.rotate(performance.now() * 0.001);
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
   ctx.strokeRect(-5, -5, size / 4, 10);
   ctx.restore();
}

let lastSize = {};

function rAFLoop() {
  const rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  const willResize = lastSize.width !== rect.width || lastSize.height !== rect.height;
  if (willResize) {
    // don't draw since we'll draw in the resizeObserver callback
    // but do record our size
    lastSize = rect;
  } else {
    draw();
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const canvas = entry.target;
    canvas.width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
    canvas.height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
    draw();
  }
})
observer.observe(canvas, { box: 'device-pixel-content-box' });
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

With this solution we only render once per frame and we get the actual device pixel size

Note: the 3rd solution changed what it's observing from `'content-box'`, which is the default, to `'device-pixel-content-box'`. If you don't make this change, then, if the user zooms in or out you will not get a resize callback since from the POV the webpage, the size of the element doesn't change on zoom. It's still just a certain number of CSS pixels.

### Solution 4: Record the size in the `ResizeObserver` callback, resize the canvas in `requestAnimationFrame` if the size changed

This solution means, given the order of operations at the top of this answer, you'll render the wrong size for 1 frame. Often that doesn't matter. In fact, run the example below and size the window and you likely won't see an issue

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.rotate(performance.now() * 0.001);
   ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
   ctx.strokeRect(-5, -5, size / 4, 10);
   ctx.restore();
}

const desiredSize = { width: 300, height: 150 };  // initial size of canvas

function rAFLoop() {
  const { width, height } = desiredSize;
  
  // only resize if we really need to since setting canvas.width/height
  // can be a heavy operation
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
  }

  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const canvas = entry.target;
    desiredSize.width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
    desiredSize.height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
  }
})
observer.observe(canvas, { box: 'device-pixel-content-box' });
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

If you size the window you likely won't see any issues with this solution. On the other hand, let's say you have sudden large changes. For example imagine you have an editor and you have an option to show/hide a pane so that the canvas area changes sizes drastically. Then, for one frame, you'll see an image the wrong size. We can demo this

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function draw() {
   const { width, height } = canvas;

   ctx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
   ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(width / 2, height / 2);
   const size = Math.min(width, height);
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(0, 0, size / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
   ctx.fill();
   ctx.stokeStyle = 'red';
   ctx.lineWidth = 20;
   ctx.strokeRect(-size / 2.5, -size / 2.5, size / 1.25, size / 1.25);
   ctx.lineWidth = 3;
   ctx.rotate(performance.now() * 0.001);
   ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
   ctx.strokeRect(-5, -5, size / 4, 10);
   ctx.restore();
}

const desiredSize = { width: 300, height: 150 };  // initial size of canvas

function rAFLoop() {
  const { width, height } = desiredSize;
  
  // only resize if we really need to since setting canvas.width/height
  // can be a heavy operation
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
  }
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);
}
requestAnimationFrame(rAFLoop);

const observer = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
  for (const entry of entries) {
    const canvas = entry.target;
    desiredSize.width = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].inlineSize;
    desiredSize.height = entry.devicePixelContentBoxSize[0].blockSize;
  }
})
observer.observe(canvas, { box: 'device-pixel-content-box' });

const uiElem = document.querySelector('#ui');
setInterval(() => {
  ui.style.display = ui.style.display === '' ? 'none' : '';
}, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: block;
}
#outer {
 display: flex;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#outer>* {
 flex: 1 1 50%;
 min-width: 0;
}
#ui {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div><canvas></canvas></div>
  <div id="ui"><div>ui pane</div></div>
</div>
```

If you watch the example above closely you'll see one frame that's the wrong size when the ui pane is hidden or shown

Which solution you choose is up to your needs. If your drawing is not that heavy, drawing twice, once in rAF, once in the resize observer might be fine. Or, if you don't expect the user to resize often (note: this isn't about resizing just the window, plenty of webpages have panes with sliders that let you adjust the size of areas where all the same issues exist)

If you don't care about pixel perfection then the 2nd solution is fine too. For example, most 3d games, AFAIK, don't care about pixel perfection. They are already rendering bilinear filtered textures and often rendering to lower-resolutions and rescaling.

If you do care about pixel perfection then the 3rd solution works.

note: As of 2014-01-18 Safari still does not support `devicePixelContentBoxSize`

Comment: Don't you want to early exit in #3 instead of drawing both in rAF and in the RO callback? And I guess a 4th solution would be to lose pixel perfection for just one frame, so that in RO callback you just update the size and the next frame you have pixel perfect back.

Comment: Thanks for noticing. Fixed I think. I somehow copied the wrong code. I'm not sure the 4th solution is good. Here's an example of where it fails: https://codepen.io/greggman/pen/VwRbWeZ  In which case, it really belongs in the question as a non-solution. Though it might be good enough in many situations.

Comment: Yes #3 looks more like it ;-). For my 4th solution, I was actually talking about using both the imprecise results from `getBoundingClientRect() * devicePixelRatio` & the correct ones from RO, but use the imprecise one only in the "resizing" frame, so that it only loses the pixel-perfection for that frame, but still is the "almost" correct size (which is probably fine for an animation) https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/zYbwzwe

Comment: Yea, that would be a 5th solution? Is that better or worse? It feels like just pick #3 if you want things to work with pixel perfection? I added #4 (without the extra code of tracking which size to use)

Comment: I guess it's more like a correct #4. For instance at work I often do animated charts, but most of the time they are  actually static and having pixel perfect when static is great. But if during the resizing they lose pixel perfection it's not visible, at least certainly less than having a wrong sized canvas like in your examples.

Comment: If your charts are static then why are you rendering with rAF? You can just use the first non-rAF example in the question? Or did you mean their size is static but the charts are animated? In any case, #4+ doesn't seem like less work than #3 and still has an off by one error so why chose it over #3?

Comment: They are *sometimes* animated. Going from one state to another. The animation loop isn't always active indeed, but during resize and during aesthetics changes it is. And this solution is off by one frame only regarding the pixel-perfection. Moving the rendering into the resizeobserver callback as in #3 may not always be possible. You can have other code depending on the fact your canvas has been rendered in an earlier rAF for instance. But you're right, that doesn't add much benefit if you can split your drawing code like that.